# Issue with code for SDA/SCL TC9548A Multiplexer and HMC5883L sensors

Tags: arduino-uno, wires, multiplexer, magnetometer

This is my first time posting on this forum, so I hope my question is appropriate here. My team is working with the Adafruit TCA9548A 1-to-8 I2C Multiplexer Breakout board to try and read from six HMC5883L Breakout sensors, and I am in the process of trying to look at their code to solve a problem. For some reason, code does not run at all unless you comment out a certain line in the code. Once it is commented out, the code runs as expected.

Now, we have to initialize it in setup(), but the statement tcaselect(0) statement was commented out so it doesn't initialize the 0th sensor in setup(). We can keep the other part, the if(mag0.begin()) statement, and it works as expected. However, if we uncomment out tcaselect(0) in setup, the entire code crashes, and all we see are 'HM' in the display window. A very basic schematic is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fy94vU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I ran some tests with my team, and when all six HMC5883Ls and the single TCA9548 multiplexer were connected on the same breadboard according to the schematic, they worked when tcaselect(0) in setup() was not commented out. Next, we had an apparatus to hold the six sensors, and we had it connected with long lengths of wire, the same as the schematic. We hooked it up to the same breadboard, and the code would not run unless tcaselect(0) in setup was commented out. This seems strange to me that they would work when connected on the breadboard, but when spread out and connected to the breadboard via long wires, they would not work unless that code was commented out.

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tca9548a-1-to-8-i2c-multiplexer-breakout?view=all

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-hmc5883l-breakout-triple-axis-magnetometer-compass-sensor/overview

EDIT: Someone mentioned that wires might have problems with the SDA/SCL bus, so the wires that we're using are 4-pin ribbon cables, 2.54 mm pitch. A very rough schematic of the container that we're using is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYOkIn.png)</sup>

Sorry for the roughness. It's the best I can do to show how the container is assembled. There's an 8x8 in. box where the components are stored, so the sensors go from various locations in the apparatus to the center box where the Pi, Arduino, and breadboard are placed. The nodes in the schematic represent the locations of the sensors. Given the rough dimensions, the longest distance for one of the sensors is around 56.8 inches (or approx. 1.45 meters) accounting for some extra wiring.

Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_HMC5883_U.h>

#define TCAADDR 0x70

/* Assign a unique ID to this sensor at the same time */
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag0 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(0);
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag1 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(1);
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag2 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(2);
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag3 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(3);
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag4 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(4);
Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified mag5 = Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified(5);

//Display details of sensor here
void displaySensorDetails(Adafruit_HMC5883_Unified *mag){
  sensor_t sensor;
  mag->getSensor(&sensor);
  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.print  ("Sensor:       "); Serial.println(sensor.name);
  Serial.print  ("Driver Ver:   "); Serial.println(sensor.version);
  Serial.print  ("Unique ID:    "); Serial.println(sensor.sensor_id);
  Serial.print  ("Max Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.max_value);         Serial.println(" uT");
  Serial.print  ("Min Value:    "); Serial.print(sensor.min_value); Serial.println(" uT");
  Serial.print  ("Resolution:   "); Serial.print(sensor.resolution); Serial.println(" uT");  
  Serial.println("------------------------------------");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(500);
}

//Given sensor i, select and write to it
void tcaselect(uint8_t i) {
  if (i > 7) return; 
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCAADDR);
  Wire.write(1 << i);
  Wire.endTransmission();  
}

    void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  /* Initialise the 0st sensor */
   //tcaselect(0);
   if(!mag0.begin())  {
    /* There was a problem detecting the HMC5883 ... check your connections */
    Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");
   }

  /* Initialise Sensors 1-6 */
  tcaselect(1);  if(!mag1.begin())  {  Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");  }  
  tcaselect(2);  if(!mag2.begin())  {  Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");  }
  tcaselect(3);  if(!mag3.begin())  {  Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");  }
  tcaselect(4);  if(!mag4.begin())  {  Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");  }
  tcaselect(5);  if(!mag5.begin())  {  Serial.println("Ooops, no HMC5883 detected ... Check your wiring!");  }


}

void loop() {
  /* Get a new sensor event */ 
  sensors_event_t event0;  sensors_event_t event1; 
  sensors_event_t event2;  sensors_event_t event3;
  sensors_event_t event4;  sensors_event_t event5;

  tcaselect(0);  mag0.getEvent(&event0);  tcaselect(1);  mag1.getEvent(&event1);
  tcaselect(2);  mag2.getEvent(&event2);  tcaselect(3);  mag3.getEvent(&event3);
  tcaselect(4);  mag4.getEvent(&event4);  tcaselect(5);  mag5.getEvent(&event5);  

  /* Display the results (magnetic vector values are in micro-Tesla (uT)) */
  Serial.print(event1.magnetic.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event1.magnetic.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event1.magnetic.z); Serial.print("  ");

  Serial.print(event2.magnetic.x);      Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event2.magnetic.y);      Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event2.magnetic.z + 37); Serial.print("  ");

  Serial.print(event3.magnetic.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event3.magnetic.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event3.magnetic.z); Serial.print("  ");

  Serial.print(event4.magnetic.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event4.magnetic.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event4.magnetic.z + 37); Serial.print("  ");

  Serial.print(event5.magnetic.x); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event5.magnetic.y); Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.print(event5.magnetic.z); Serial.print("  ");

  delay(500);
}
```

EDIT: Big news, I tried using only two sensors and 1.5m cables and adding 10k pullup resistors from VCC to SDL/SCA on the respective sensors; with these changes, they seem to work even with tcaselect(0) not commented out in setup, though I only used two sensors rather than six. The HMC5883L sensor breakout board contains 10k pullup resistors already, so with another 10k resistor per line, it would make it 5k. Would this value be too much, or is it fine? I looked at the datasheet of the sensor itself, but I can't find anything on what value the input impedance would be for SCL/SDA.

Also, on another related note, one of my sensors had wires crossed deliberately, so SCL and SDA are separated by GND and VCC in the cable. I'm still running tests to see if I need to do this, but is it recommended to do so even if it is not necessary for correct operation? Someone mentioned that having SCL/SDA next to each other would be bad if they cause problems with crosstalk/interference.

Comment: You could follow that tutorial from start to finish. There is a I2C scanner for each of the 8 channels. You could run that to see what it finds. How many pullup resistors did you add. I think that you need 2 pullup resistors that are on the multiplexer module, and 16 more pullup resistors. Did you read the note about the pullups in the "I2C Multiplexed-Side pins" paragraph ? Don't select a channel without pullups, when SDA or SCL is low, the Arduino I2C scanner stops working.

Comment: It stops at your dummy sensor ? What is a hardware dummy I2C sensor ? I have never heard of it before. Did you ask patent for it ? You might be the only one in the world that has one.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Sorry, I use the term dummy sensor to denote a sensor that is attached to the setup, but we don't use it. It's just another HMC5883L, but we don't use it.

Comment: The HMC5883L breakout board has 10k pullup resistors from the SCL/SDA pins to VCC, so there's no problems there. For the multiplexer itself, we didn't add any pull up resistors. I saw the paragraph, but with the pull ups on the sensor, it should be fine, right?

Comment: Yes, pullup resistors on the HMC5883L module are fine. Select only the channels that have the pullup resistors. When nothing is running and Wire.begin() has been called, all SDA and SCL pins on both sides of the multiplexer should be high.

Comment: I apologize, but this doesn't exactly help with my problem. All of the sensors that we are using contain pullup resistors. It's just that something seems to happen when we don't have a sensor connected to SD/SC0 on the multiplexer, so we can't read from the other sensors as well. Looking at tcaselect, it seems to write an 8-bit signal to TCAADDR, but with a '1' bit depending on the device. If that's the case, then TCAADDR should be no problem.

Comment: @user101402 did you try with just one sensor?

Comment: Yes, I tried it with one sensor on a breadboard. Then I moved up to two, three, and then seven sensors. After that, I hooked up the sensors to sections of an apparatus and connected them to the breadboard with long wires. The wires were properly connected according to my new schematic, but it wouldn't work unless that line of code was not commented out.

Comment: How long are the wires ? what kind of wires ? Putting SDA and SCL in a ribbon cable is very bad for the signals. The Adafruit multiplexer has 10k pullup resistors for the signals to the Arduino. That means it might work up to 50 cm. Try to add pullup resistors at the Arduino, perhaps 3k3 or 4k7. They will be parallel the 10k and parallel the internal 50k pullup resistors of the Arduino board. You might want to try Wire.setClock(50000L) to lower the I2C clock.

Comment: Maybe your bus capacity is too big?

Comment: The bus capacity seems okay, as it handled 7 sensors when all on a breadboard. The wires are 4-pin ribbon cables, and length varies depending on the location. I'll edit my post once I get the measurements, but for the pullup resistors, would they be placed on the A4/A5 lines to +5V? I'm looking at the schematic (Uno Rev 3), but I don't see where the 50k/10k resistors are. The sensors and the multiplexer already have pull up resistors on them. Also, how would lowering the I2C clock help with tcaselect(0)? It doesn't explain how this line works with sensors on the breadboard but not with wires.

Comment: A flat ribbon cable with SDA and SCL next to each other is the worst possible wiring for a I2C bus. The SDA and SCL should have minimal capacitance to GND and VCC and they should not interfere with each other. If a pulse from SCL appears on SDA (or the other way around) that will make it impossible to make the I2C bus work. Capacitance to GND and VCC can be solved (for a part) by lowering the value of the pullup resistors and by lowering the I2C clock. But crosstalk between SDA and SCL can not be prevented that way. You have not told us yet how long the wires are.

Comment: I put down the distance from the center box to the farthest placed sensor, being around 1.45m, so that's approximately how long the wires are. The shortest distance is around 10 inches or so. I understand what you're saying about the I2C bus and the wire placements, but this is what I have to work with. I can add another resistor in parallel to reduce pull up value, Nevertheless, the strange issue still remains that with tcaselect(0) commented out in setup, all sensors were able to be read from. It's strange that this line of code is commented; kind of feels like it shouldn't be.

Comment: I'm sorry, but SDA and SCL next to each other in a flat ribbon cable is wrong, you should refuse to work with that. You can split the wires over the complete length of the ribbon cable, all of them. That will improve the signals. Did you forget the Wire.begin ? Perhaps some hardware needs time to power up. You could add a delay of 500ms before starting to use the I2C bus.

Comment: Jot, Thanks for your comment. I think that one of my issues is that I needed pull-up resistors. I used 10k resistors for the SDA/SCL lines on the sensors, so that worked with the cable. In regards to your comment on the cable, rather than having SDA and SCL next to each other, I moved the soldered wires around at the sensor so along the cable, SCL was on one side, SDA was on the other, with GND and VCC in between the two. That seems to work alongside the additional pull up resistors to get everything working, though I only tested it with two sensors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have, but have you connected the grounds together?

Have you tried 1 sensor on SD/C0 and then moving it to SD/C1 it should stop working, so the fault has to be with SD/C0.

Looking at your code, is there a reason you haven't initialised sensor 0?

```
 /* Initialise Sensors 1-6 */
```

So it looks to me as the fault is caused by you not calling `begin()` on `mag0`

Comment: We connected the grounds together; they all lead to a node on the breadboard which feeds back to the Arduino. We tried your suggestion with SD/C0 and SD/C1, but the results were the same. I'll ask the team to try again since I can't exactly test it because I'm not on site with the device. The reason why we haven't initialized sensor 0 with tcaselect(0) was that it was causing our code to hang. Once we commented it out, the code continued, and we could read from all sensors. The guy in charge tested it, commented out stuff, and found that this was the issue, though we still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try bumping the empty to the last slot and changing your for loop to only iterate the first 7.

Serial prints along the way help debugging